# Probability of Five Distinct Faces When Five Dice Are Rolled

Tags: probability, dice

This question is very similar to one asked on [Probability of All Distinct Faces When Six Dice Are Rolled](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105300/probability-of-all-distinct-faces-when-six-dice-are-rolled)

Now mine has a little spin on it and is: if five fair dice are rolled what is probability that **FIVE** numbers will appear exactly once?

If anyone is interested, my main goal is making a python script that can calculate the probability, since I'm new to this, this is what I got (though am positive it's wrong):

```
def numOne(roll):
  return len([dice1 for dice1 in roll if dice1 == 1])
def numTwo(roll):
  return len([dice2 for dice2 in roll if dice2 == 2])
def numThree(roll):
  return len([dice3 for dice3 in roll if dice3 == 3])
def numFour(roll):
  return len([dice4 for dice4 in roll if dice4 == 4])
def numFive(roll):
  return len([dice5 for dice5 in roll if dice5 == 5])
def numSix(roll):
  return len([dice6 for dice6 in roll if dice6 == 6])

r = range(1,7)
sample = [(i,j,k,l,m) for i in r for j in r for k in r \ 
                      for l in r for m in r]
event = [roll for roll in sample if numOne(roll)==1 and numTwo(roll)==1 and 
numThree(roll)==1 and numFour(roll)==1 and numFive(roll)==1 or 
numSix(roll)==1]

print(len(event) / len(sample))
```

The output is: 0.417309670781893 or 3245 / 7776

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Your `event` is wrong.  The last few entries shows `... (6, 5, 5, 5, 1), (6, 5, 5, 5, 2), (6, 5, 5, 5, 3), (6, 5, 5, 5, 4), (6, 5, 5, 5, 5)]`.

Comment: Indeed. I have very little knowledge of python (started 2 days ago) and in  `event` I made the program check for the first five distinct faces, in other words, only faces with 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 number and leaving the last face (which is 6) to be a choice rather than something necessary which is stupid I know...

Comment: IMHO, a combinatoric argument much easier than debugging code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know enough about Python to see what is going wrong, but yes, something is wrong.

You can easily calculate the probability like this:

If you want five different faces, then for the first die you have $6$ possibilities, then for the second there will be $5$ left, then for the third there will be $4$ left, etc.

So, out of $6^5=7776$ possible outcomes, there will be $6\cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2=720$ where the five dice have different faces.

Thus, the probability is $$\frac{720}{7776}$$

Comment: Amazing, Thanks a bunch! If you would like to know what's going on in there. What I did is I made the program go through the whole 6^5 possible outcomes and check for the **first five** distinct faces, in other words, only faces with 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 number and leaving the last face (which is 6) to be a **choice** rather than something **necessary** which is very stupid to do but yeah well, I tried my best. Thanks again.